# Track the process that initiated a reboot on Ubunu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, reboot, log

My computer gracefully restarted while it was idle. `last reboot` shows the following output:

`reboot system boot  4.18.0-21-generi Tue Jun 11 18:14 - 13:02  (18:47)`

My question is: is there another log I can look at which will show me the cause of this reboot? The computer is fairly new so I doubt its a hardware issue, it has only happened once.

I'm concerned because I think the only way the computer can gracefully restart is if a user has root privileges, so I'm wondering if this was executed remotely.

How can I track the process that initiated this reboot?

Comment: See the output of `sudo journalctl --since "2018-08-30 14:10:10" --until "2018-09-02 12:05:50"
` to filter ( not change the dates) or `sudo journalctl` to find what gives!

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen thanks! checking it out now. I'm guessing nothing escapes the `journal` logs?

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen It seems that the reboot is not showing up in the journal logs. It's very weird. the logs for that reboot are not recorded.... I mean it is not even showing up on last reboot. `18:14` was when I turned on my computer, and the restart happened after that, but it is nowhere to be found... very stramge

Comment: Where you connected to the internet when you rebooted?

Comment: Yes I was @GeorgeUdosen, I was connected when the computer suddenly rebooted. I cant seem to see any of the activities that happen when the computer boots up.

Comment: Try `last` command to see who was logged in.

Comment: Shows my normal user as the logged in user.

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen there does seem to be an update that happened prior to the restart, would it be possible for the update to have caused an automatic reboot and not log it ??

Comment: And if you look through the records it shows only you?

Comment: Yep, when I go through the records in `last` it shows only me as the logged in user

Comment: I have never known updates to act in this manner. I advise you watch your system for suspicious activities and perhaps disconnection from the internet and then reboot, open your process monitor and then connect again and observe any odd activity.

Comment: I observed a pattern in the logs -- I am able to reproduce this error ` Object .Gjs_AppIndicatorIconActor__1 (0x55c6c5d154c0), has been already finalized. Impossible to set any property to it` everytime the computer sleeps when untouched. The reboot to my system happened when it was in "sleep mode" but the reboot is not logged.. Could the error have caused a reboot that isn't logged ?